# How to get page history in JSON using Wikipedia API?

Tags: json, wikipedia-api

Sending a request such as:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=America&offset=&limit=20&action=history

will get the history page of a particular subject with a maximum of 20 edits listed. Is there a way to use the API to return a list of edits and their dates in JSON?

I searched the documentation but can't find anything.

Comment: So, could you get the Wikipedia history section?
I can't find the right answer. please help me

Answer (score 2):

To get edit dates you need to use MediaWiki API with property [revisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Brevisions) and `rvprop=timestamp`:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&rvlimit=20&titles=America&rvlimit=5&rvprop=timestamp
```

To get other additional revision information as content, user, comment etc., add them to **rvprop**:

```
&rvprop=timestamp|content|user|comment
```